# Exception: Cell reference out of range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on making a google sheets function on App Script. I'm kind of a beginner and I'm not too familiar with it's classes and methods. Here's my code:

```
function updateBudget(category, amount) {
  
  var budgetTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("OG!A6:E16");

  for(var i = 6; i <= 16; i++){
    if(category == budgetTable.getCell(i, 1).getValue()){
      var cell = budgetTable.getCell(i, 5);
      if(!cell.isEmpty()){
        cell.setValue(cell.getValue() + amount);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I keep getting the following error on line 6 (the bolded line):
Exception: Cell reference out of range

NOTE: my for loop starts from 6 to 16 because those are the rows I want the code to run on, while 1 and 5 are the column numbers.

I tried following the code and I don't see how it would be out of range.

Comment: getCell(1,1) gets the value in col 1 and row 6 getCell(1, 5) gets the value in col 5 and row 6 as it states in the documentation it's all relative to the range. So your row indices much go from 1 to 11 12 to 16 are out of range